# 'Nested' foreign key relationship

Tags: sql, t-sql, relational-database

A Product has a code (and other attributes). A Product is available in various countries, with a different name in each. A Packaged Product is a product in a particular pack size.

An invoice detail line will hold a package_code and a country_code. The permissible countries for a PackagedProduct are restricted by the contents of the ProductCountry table, i.e. the PackagedProduct is only available in a given Country if the Product is available in that Country.

Here's my approach (Country and InvoiceDetail tables omitted):

```
create table Product (
    product_code varchar(15),
    strength varchar(10),
    -- other Product attributes
    constraint pk_Product primary key (product_code)
    );

create table ProductCountry (
    product_code varchar(15),
    country_code char(2),
    local_name varchar(100),
    constraint pk_ProductCountry primary key (product_code, country_code),
    foreign key (product_code) references Product(product_code),
    foreign key (country_code) references Country(country_code)
    );

create table PackagedProduct (
    package_code varchar(20),
    product_code varchar(15),
    pack_size int,
    constraint pk_PackagedProduct primary key (package_code),
    foreign key (product_code) references Product(product_code)
    );
```

My problem is that this design does not restrict Invoice Detail records to valid combinations of PackagedProduct and Country.

Can we improve this design?

Comment: You may want to look at [CHECK constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/unique-constraints-and-check-constraints?view=sql-server-2017#Check) and [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for ways of performing more complex data validation. Ponder carefully what `update` and `delete` statements should do, e.g. if a product is no longer offered in Elbonia what becomes of `InvoiceDetails` that reflect shipments to the muddy land.

Comment: This is a faq. You can constrain this declaratively via compound PKs & FKs that include product & country.

Comment: @HABO yes I feared that I may have to resort to manual constraints. I think the Elbonia invoice remains valid - we just won't make any more in future!

Comment: @philipxy by compound FK's, do you mean FKs referencing more than one column? I don't see how that addresses the problem, would you care to spell it out for me using my example?

Comment: "compound/composite key" is a google away. I don't have time or my faq list now. Meanwhile from my comments list: Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. PS The idea is to have InvoiceDetail PK (invoice, product, country) & FK (product, country) to ProductCountry. (PK (product) to Product is then implied.)

Comment: @philipxy - There is a subtlety to the problem that I may not have made clear enough. An Invoice Detail does not hold a Product Code, it holds a Package Code. That's why a composite key to ProductCountry does not apply here. Still, thanks for your efforts on this.

Comment: Please give DDL for all relevant tables. [mcve]. Please clarify via edits not comments. You want restrict InvoiceDetail but you haven't even given it. PS The point is that you can add product, package & country columns as needed for FKs to constrain as you desire.